# Uneable to parse schema file - XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm new with XML and XML schema. I use Notepad++ to validate my .xml but something doesn't work, Notepad returns me this error: "Unable to parse schema file, Parsing error at line 32: Element complexContent:The content is not valid Expected is (annotation?,(restriction | extension))".
My productivprocess.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="working">
    <xs:complexType name="working">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="lot" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType name="lot">
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="atomicity" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    </xs:all>
                    <xs:attribute name="lotname" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="resources" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:element name="resource" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType name="resource">
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="available" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                                    <xs:element name="time" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                                </xs:all>
                                <xs:attribute name="resourcename" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:complexContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>   
            <xs:element name="process" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType name="process">
                    <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="lot" type="lot" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                            <xs:element name="phase" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType name="phase" mixed="true">
                                    <xs:all>
                                        <xs:element name="power" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                                        <xs:element name="isDiff" type="xs:boolean"/>
                                        <xs:element name="timeDistribution" type="xs:boolean"/>
                                        <xs:element name="resource" type="resource"/>
                                    </xs:all>
                                <xs:attribute name="phasename" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="specialphase" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:element name="phase" type="phase" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="specialphasename" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="processname" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
```

This my .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<working xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="productiveprocess.xsd">
    <lot name="lot1">
        <atomicity>0</atomicity><!-- 0 means indivisible -->
    </lot>
    <lot name="lot2">
        <atomicity>0</atomicity>
    </lot>
    <resources>
        <resource resourcename="A1">
            <resourcenumber>4</resourcenumber>
            <time>1h</time>
        </resource>
        <resource resourcename="A2">
            <resourcenumber>2</resourcenumber>
            <time>30min</time>
        </resource>
        <resource resourcename="A3">
            <resourcenumber>1</resourcenumber>
            <time>2h</time>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <process name="process1">
        <lot ref="lot1"> <!-- THis could be equal to previuosly lot1 -->
            <atomicity>0</atomicity>
        </lot>
        <phase name="phase1">
            <power>5</power>
            <isDiff>0</isDiff> <!-- boolean, 0 not deferrable 1 deferrable-->
            <timeDistribution>0</timeDistribution> 
            <resource ref="A1"></resource> <!-- This could be equal to 
previuosly "A2" resource-->
        </phase>
        <phase name="phase2">
            <power>3</power>
            <isDiff>0</isDiff>
            <timeDistribution>1</timeDistribution>
            <resource ref="A2"></resource>
        </phase>
        <phase name="phase3">
            <power>6</power>
            <isDiff>0</isDiff>
            <timeDistribution>1</timeDistribution>
            <resource ref="A3"></resource>
        </phase>
        <specialphase name="specialphase4">
            <phase ref="phase2"></phase> <!-- This could be equal to previuosly phase2-->
            <phase ref="phase3"></phase>
        </specialphase>
    </process>
    <process name="process2">
        <lot ref="lot2">
            <atomicity>0</atomicity>
        </lot>
        <phase name="phase1">
            <power>5</power>
            <isDiff>0</isDiff>
            <timeDistribution>0</timeDistribution>
            <resource ref="A1"></resource>
        </phase>
        <phase name="phase2">
            <power>3</power>
            <isDiff>0</isDiff>
            <distrTempo>1</distrTempo>
            <resource ref="A2"></resource>
        </phase>
        <phase name="phase3">
            <power>6</power>
            <isDiff>0</isDiff>
            <timeDistribution>1</timeDistribution>
            <resource ref="A3"></resource>
        </phase>
        <specialphase name="specialphase4">
            <phase ref="phase2"></phase> 
            <phase ref="phase3"></phase>
        </specialphase>
    </process>
</working>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema file is missing the closing `</xs:schema>` tag.

You can't use the attribute `name` in the `<xs:complexType>` element.

Your use of `<xs:complexContent>` is either unnecessary or the wrong element, depending on what you require.

`<xs:attribute>` is invalid under `<xs:element>` and looks unnecessary.

You have three self-referencing `type` declarations for lot, phase and resource - they look unnecessary.

All the above just relates to syntax errors in the schema. However, as I noted below, generally a schema consists of a series of element definitions which are then used in other definitions - note, this is very simplistic - rather than a definition of the entire document in one go.

For instance, I generated a sample schema using XMLSpy for your XML. The first definition it gives is

```
<xs:element name="working">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="lot" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="resources"/>
            <xs:element ref="process" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

You would then go on to define the elements "lot", "resources" and "process" as compexTypes, etc.

For example,

```xml
<xs:element name="lot">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="atomicity"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="ref">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="lot1"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="lot2"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="name">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="lot1"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="lot2"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

There are two ways (at least) of doing this. Either define an element and reference it, e.g.

```xml
<xs:element name="resources">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="resource" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

then

```
<xs:element ref="resources"/>
```

or define a type and define an element of that type, e.g.

```
<xs:complexType name="resourcesType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="resource" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

then

```
<xs:element name="resources" type="resourcesType"/>
```

Note, than you can name a free-standing complexType but not on used in the definition of an element. This can be useful if you want to use the same type multiple times within the document but with a different name for each instance.

Here is the entire generated schema. I suggest you go through it comparing it to your XML to get an idea of how schemas are structured. But don't just take this generated schema as it is; once you get the idea you should be able to simplify and/or restructure it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2007 sp2 (http://www.altova.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com">
    <xs:element name="working">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="lot" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="resources"/>
                <xs:element ref="process" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="timeDistribution">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="time">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="1h"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="2h"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="30min"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="specialphase">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="phase" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="specialphase4"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="resources">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="resource" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="resourcenumber">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="resource">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element ref="resourcenumber"/>
                <xs:element ref="time"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="resourcename">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="A1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="A2"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="A3"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="ref">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="A1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="A2"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="A3"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="process">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="lot"/>
                <xs:element ref="phase" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="specialphase"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="process1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="process2"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="power">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="phase">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element ref="power"/>
                <xs:element ref="isDiff"/>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element ref="distrTempo"/>
                    <xs:element ref="timeDistribution"/>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="resource"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ref">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="phase2"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="phase3"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="name">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="phase1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="phase2"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="phase3"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="lot">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="atomicity"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ref">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="lot1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="lot2"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="name">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="lot1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="lot2"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="isDiff">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="distrTempo">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="atomicity">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I have the closing tag   </xs:schema>, but I don't copy it here. Sorry for mistake.  
I use attribute name in <xs:complexType> because I want to reuse thi type after. How can I resolve this? 
The self-referencing is to do what I say before.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I think you may be confusing the definition of elements with the definition of the document structure. Generally a schema consists of a series of element definitions which are then used in other definitions - note, this is very simplistic - rather than a definition of the entire document in one go. I'll update the answer to give you a guide.

Comment: Than you for the help. The attributes "ref" and "name" are to specify the self-reference and the name of lot?
For examples if I create another lot with name="lot8" the xml is valid yet?

Comment: So I give to my complexType a name?

Comment: I'm struggling in the comments - I'll add something to the answer.

Comment: When in XML I want to refer to one element created before is good use ref="element name"? For example: <lot name="lot1"/>... <process><lot ref="lot1"/></process>

Comment: ref is used in a schema rather than a document.

Comment: So how can I reference to my element?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean.

Comment: In my xml file above, I write a comment next to <lot> tag in process, this lot could be the lot1 declared in the firsts rows of my xml file.

Comment: No, you're getting confused between schemas and XML. You really need to do an XML tutorial - there are plenty online.